# Sites blocking copying of text

Tags: web

It seems to be a trend - websites that prevent copying of their text. cNet.com is one. Is there a way to overcome this apart from creating an image of the wanted text.

I need to quote short selections in my forum discussions and it is only "fair use" not plagiarism or copyright infringement.

Comment: Disable JavaScript and copy the text. Then enable it as some webpage need it to show contents properly.

Comment: In certain browsers e.g. Chrome, you can disable JS support for certain sites with exception list and enables content copying from it.

Answer (score 2):

These sites use JavaScript to disable the copying of text, as well as other features such as right-clicking.  Chrome has several [addons](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20addon%20disable%20javascript&oq=chrome%20addon%20disab&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.14688j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that can toggle JavaScript on and off.  Firefox does as well.

The first thing to try is viewing the page source, i.e. the code that makes the site.  This may or may not show you the text you want to copy, due to how JavaScript works.  Different browsers use different methods to view the page source, but that is easy to google an answer for.

Disabling JavaScript may or may not work for you though.  Disabling JavaScript will require reloading the page.  This may result in the page not functioning properly and not displaying the text you want to copy.

A text based browser like [Links](http://links.twibright.com/), or [Brow.Sh](https://www.brow.sh/) may also work, as they support JavaScript.  So you may be able to capture the text output with a redirection.